# Eslint runtime react/function-component-definition error React 18

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, react-18

I’m getting the following error message on screen while run npm run start command.

Compiled with errors -

```
[eslint] Function component is not a function declaration, react/function-component-definition
```

I am using eslint, configured with airbnb, also added rules to allow arrow style syntax else it keeps giving me error in Vscode to convert to function style and not arrow one. I have defined my eslint.json file and also used babel react preset but this error just doesn’t seem to go. I use React 18 and Node 18 in package.json.

Also there’s some console logs showing up while I run for index.HTML, externalSVG file (which I never use), env configs etc.

```
Unexpected token <
```

Does anyone help on this too?

Someone please help.